# Ionic3 / Android - connect via Oauth2 to a site that supports only grant type "Authorisation code"?

Tags: oauth-2.0, ionic3

**[I KNOW](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2)** OAuth 2 defines four grant types, each of which is useful in different cases.

I would like to connect my Ionic app to a website that supports only the "Authorization Code" grant type.

Is this possible? If so, what do I use for packages/libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't CAN you do it, but SHOULD you do it.  As part of the Authorization Code grant type you need to exchange an Authorization Code for an Access Token by using a Client ID and Secret.  This Secret is the downfall here.  You can't securely hold that Secret in a client-side app (aka Ionic 3).  That's why Ionic would normally use the Implicit flow (if deployed as a SPA), or the Authorization Code Grant using Proof Key for Code Exchange - PKCE (if deployed as a native app).

Now that said, you could stand up a server-side API that your Ionic client could call, and that server-side API may be able to do some of this OAuth handshake on behalf of the client.  That may be a creative workaround.  Not sure how "pure" that solution would be.  Auth0's site has some helpful docs on things like this:

- https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use
- https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/authorization-code

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time I found a very nice way to handle the Oauth2 flow from **Ionic2**. See [this nice article](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/using-an-oauth-2-0-service-within-an-ionic-2-mobile-app/).

A similar tricks works also for **Android**, see the next example below.

For **Ionic** the heart is using the redirect-url "http://localhost/callback".

```
public facebookLogin(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + "CLIENT_ID_HERE" + "&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback&response_type=token&scope=email", "_blank", "location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes");
        browserRef.addEventListener("loadstart", (event) => {
            if ((event.url).indexOf("http://localhost/callback") === 0) {
                browserRef.removeEventListener("exit", (event) => {});
                browserRef.close();
                var responseParameters = ((event.url).split("#")[1]).split("&");
                var parsedResponse = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < responseParameters.length; i++) {
                    parsedResponse[responseParameters[i].split("=")[0]] = responseParameters[i].split("=")[1];
                }
                if (parsedResponse["access_token"] !== undefined && parsedResponse["access_token"] !== null) {
                    resolve(parsedResponse);
                } else {
                    reject("Problem authenticating with Facebook");
                }
            }
        });
        browserRef.addEventListener("exit", function(event) {
            reject("The Facebook sign in flow was canceled");
        });
    });
}
```

For **Android**, I created a similar solution that uses the real Oauth2 "authorization_code" flow. This was the only supported solution for mobiles. The app with this 'authorization_code' flow works very well.

The crucial part is:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() { 
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading( WebView view, String url) {
        if( url.startsWith( "http://localhost/callback")) {
           String code = url.replaceFirst("^.*\\?code=([^&]+)&state.*$", "$1");
           // get the other tokens via a REST JSON call
```